# Google Chart - two date series on the same chart

Tags: google-visualization

I have data about earnings occurred on some dates:

```
['2013-02-13',100],['2013-03-20',200],['2013-04-11',160]
```

and data about costs occurred on some other dates:

```
['2013-02-22',60],['2013-03-04',90],['2013-03-25',110]
```

So X-axis is continuous one (date), and Y-axis represents earning/cost values (number). I'd like to represent these two date-value series on the same chart. They share the same timeline but events occurred on different dates?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, you just need to join the two data sets, using the [google.visualization.data.join](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_join) method:

```
var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
```

If you draw a chart using this method, you will have two series of data that can be charted together.  See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/XF7JE/

Incidentally, with your dates input like that, you will get a discrete axis, not a continuous axis.  You need to input the dates as javascript Date objects to get a continuous axis.

Comment: What do you mean by "two graphs on one chart"?  I edited my answer above with a more complete explanation and a demo in case that helps.

Comment: That's it now!. Thank you asgallant very very much! I didn't know what to define as key and column parameters of join method!

Comment: I tried to join two already joined data table (in order to have 4 graphs on chart) but it does not show what I expected: http://jsfiddle.net/sbrbot/MEtbm/

Comment: You need to include all of the columns from the first two joined tables: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/MEtbm/1/

Comment: Dear asgallant you're my hero!!! It works like a charm! (BTW, are you somehow related with Google Charts API development team?)

Comment: No, I don't work for Google, but I have met the Visualization dev team (who are awesome people, by the way).

Comment: Ok, I see in the fiddle example you give (with Google API changes to HTTPS to avoid issues) that there are two separate charts.  but when I do this with my data (x axis is dates) that one of the charts only shows as mostly dots and it appears the two series were almost literally combined into a single series... Any ideas?

Comment: @Michael, it's been a long time since I last used the Visualization API, so I'm a bit rusty, but if you can put together an example of the behavior you are seeing, I could take a look.