# Google Analytics API - Are multiple queries possible?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to generate an API call that looks as follows:

```
var dataChart5 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query:
    [
        {
        metrics: 'ga:totalEvents',
        dimensions: 'ga:date',
        'start-date': beginDate,
        'end-date': endDate,
        filters: 'ga:eventAction==Search;ga:eventCategory==Company'
        },
        {
        metrics: 'ga:totalEvents',
        dimensions: 'ga:date',
        'start-date': beginDate,
        'end-date': endDate,
        filters: 'ga:eventAction==Search;ga:eventCategory==Accommodation'
        }
    ],
    chart: {
        container: 'chart5-container',
        type: 'LINE',
        options: {
            width: '100%'
        }
    }
});
```

You'll notice there are two queries being generated for the chart. When I execute this, nothing is rendered. This tells me either the syntax is wrong or what I'm trying to do isn't supported. Is something like this possible?

Comment: what happens if you emit either individually?

Comment: Individually it works fine. I just wanted to combine them.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037925/google-chart-two-date-series-on-the-same-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you're asking is not possible with the Embed API. If you check the [documentation for the `DataChart` component](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#datachart) you'll see the `query` option takes an `Object` not an `Array`.

To do what you want, you'd have to make two queries using the [`Data`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#data) component and then render the chart yourself.