# Custom Dashboard - Displaying Sites Visits for Multiple Storefronts from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

Is it possible to graph multiple websites on the same custom dashboard chart associated with a single Google Analytics account?

We can show for a single website (i.e. number of sessions for the last month) but we can't show the same type of data for all 5 website on the same chart.

How can we do that?

Comment: I take it that you want to build the dashboard outside of the GA interface - what technology/language are you planning to use - tag analytics-sdk points to app development, but asking about charts lets me suspect this is a javascript question. Generally you cannot pass multiple queries to a  charts object (e.g. with the embed api), but you can do multiple queries, merge the results and pass them to a chart.

Comment: Also this has been asked before:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245782/google-analytics-api-are-multiple-queries-possible.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to show 5 separate "graphs", each associated with one of your websites?  Or are you asking if you could sum up the data from all 5 websites and display the aggregate on a single chart?

Comment: Yes, it's outside of the GA interface. Our own implementation using JavaScript.