# Google Visualisation - how to join multiple DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, join, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a chart with multiple lines with **Google** **Visualisation** **Api**. I use **JSON** to add data into the Chart.

There are multiple **DataTables** created at the beginning - the number of tables is equal to number of **JSON** keys.

**EDIT:** I've found the answer for the original problem - without loop. [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18039996/3371056) - the answer is about drawing two lines in one chart. In the comment, there is an answer how to do this with multiple lines - this JSFiddle: [JSFiddle - Multiple lines](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/MEtbm/1/) But I can't still figure out how to use this answer in my case.

The problem is that it draws only two lines (first and last)? I suppose that it's caused in this line:

```
joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData, datatable, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
```

Which is a try to join all DataTables, so all lines should be visible on a chart. But in fact, I don't have a clue why it doesn't work correctly.

**JOIN Doc:** [Join](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_join)

This is the whole joining loop:

```
    var joinedData = datas[0];
    $.each(datas, function (index, data1) {
        if (index != 0) {
            joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData, data1, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
        }
    });
```

And this is the whole script - or better [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/milanoo/XF7JE/382/)

```
function drawChart() {
        var google_chart_json = {"Whirpool.cz": [[[2016, 11, 2], 156.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 69.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 126.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 67.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 97.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 193.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 96.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 64.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 117.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 190.0]], "Mall.cz": [[[2016, 11, 2], 95.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 98.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 158.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 160.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 191.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 106.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 51.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 158.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 89.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 154.0]], "Mall.sk": [[[2016, 11, 2], 72.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 108.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 175.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 81.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 123.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 188.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 52.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 196.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 199.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 117.0]], "Teshop.cz": [[[2016, 11, 2], 93.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 71.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 59.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 101.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 86.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 139.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 110.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 75.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 183.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 156.0]], "Gamepro.cz": [[[2016, 11, 2], 89.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 104.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 62.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 190.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 172.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 109.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 183.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 88.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 89.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 106.0]], "Gamepro.sk": [[[2016, 11, 2], 133.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 173.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 102.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 151.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 119.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 172.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 139.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 177.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 174.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 141.0]], "Datart.cz": [[[2016, 11, 2], 77.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 120.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 116.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 60.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 179.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 162.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 151.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 123.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 138.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 109.0]], "Ockosice.sk": [[[2016, 11, 2], 83.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 111.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 185.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 199.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 133.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 142.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 61.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 74.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 168.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 128.0]], "Bestmarket.sk": [[[2016, 11, 2], 174.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 154.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 180.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 87.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 193.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 105.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 106.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 115.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 185.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 159.0]]};
        var datas = [];
        $.each(google_chart_json, function (key, val) {
            var domain = key;
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('date', domain + 'Date');
            data.addColumn('number', domain);


            $.each(val, function (_, scan) {
                var year = scan[0][0];
                var month = scan[0][1];
                var day = scan[0][2];
                var price = scan[1];

                data.addRows([
                    [new Date(year, month, day), price]
                ]);
            });
            datas.push(data);
        });
        var joinedData = datas[0];
        $.each(datas, function (index, datatable) {
            console.log('joining index '+index)
            if (index != 0) {
                joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData, datatable, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
            }
        });


        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
        chart.draw(joinedData, {
            height: 300,
            width: 600,
            interpolateNulls: true,
            explorer: {
                maxZoomOut: 2,
                keepInBounds: true
            },
        });
    }
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**first**, need to use the latest library (`loader.js`)
according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

include this...
`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

not this...
`<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

this will change the `load` statement from...
`google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});`

to...
`google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});`

**next**, the reason only two lines (columns) make it to the final data table,
has to do with the 5th argument (`dt1Columns`)
with each join, only the first data column is included `[1]` from the first table

instead, the argument should grow with each join
`[1]`, `[1,2]`, `[1,2,3]`

see following working snippet...

```js
function drawChart() {
    var google_chart_json = {"Whirpool.cz": [[[2016, 11, 2], 156.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 69.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 126.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 67.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 97.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 193.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 96.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 64.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 117.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 190.0]], "Mall.cz": [[[2016, 11, 2], 95.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 98.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 158.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 160.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 191.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 106.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 51.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 158.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 89.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 154.0]], "Mall.sk": [[[2016, 11, 2], 72.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 108.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 175.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 81.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 123.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 188.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 52.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 196.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 199.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 117.0]], "Teshop.cz": [[[2016, 11, 2], 93.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 71.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 59.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 101.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 86.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 139.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 110.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 75.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 183.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 156.0]], "Gamepro.cz": [[[2016, 11, 2], 89.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 104.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 62.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 190.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 172.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 109.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 183.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 88.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 89.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 106.0]], "Gamepro.sk": [[[2016, 11, 2], 133.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 173.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 102.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 151.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 119.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 172.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 139.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 177.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 174.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 141.0]], "Datart.cz": [[[2016, 11, 2], 77.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 120.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 116.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 60.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 179.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 162.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 151.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 123.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 138.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 109.0]], "Ockosice.sk": [[[2016, 11, 2], 83.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 111.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 185.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 199.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 133.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 142.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 61.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 74.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 168.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 128.0]], "Bestmarket.sk": [[[2016, 11, 2], 174.0], [[2016, 11, 3], 154.0], [[2016, 11, 4], 180.0], [[2016, 11, 5], 87.0], [[2016, 11, 6], 193.0], [[2016, 11, 7], 105.0], [[2016, 11, 8], 106.0], [[2016, 11, 9], 115.0], [[2016, 11, 10], 185.0], [[2016, 11, 11], 159.0]]};
    var datas = [];
    $.each(google_chart_json, function (key, val) {
        var domain = key;
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', domain + 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', domain);

        $.each(val, function (_, scan) {
            var year = scan[0][0];
            var month = scan[0][1];
            var day = scan[0][2];
            var price = scan[1];

            data.addRows([
                [new Date(year, month, day), price]
            ]);
        });
        datas.push(data);
    });
    var joinedData = datas[0];
    var columns = [];
    $.each(datas, function (index, datatable) {
        if (index != 0) {
            columns.push(index);
            joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData, datatable, 'full', [[0, 0]], columns, [1]);
        }
    });

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
    chart.draw(joinedData, {
        height: 300,
        width: 600,
        interpolateNulls: true,
        explorer: {
            maxZoomOut: 2,
            keepInBounds: true
        },
    });
}
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've done very similar thing - joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData, datatable, 'full', [[0, 0]], range(1, index + 1), [1]); The information about loader.js is very useful.